# ACE.OLEDBE.12.0 Failing to read any rows from some XLSX files

Tags: .net, vb.net, oledb

I am unable to read any rows from some .xlsx files. Below is the code I'm using.

```
Dim excelData As New DataTable
Using connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelPath + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes""")
    connection.Open()
    Dim dtSchema As DataTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})
    Dim sheet1Name As String = dtSchema.Rows(0).Field(Of String)("TABLE_NAME")
    Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * From [{0}]", sheet1Name), connection)
        adapter.Fill(excelData)
    End Using
End Using
```

The software reads .xlsx files created by users without any issues but some files are created by another program and the ones created by that program I am unable to read. I created a new excel file and cut and pasted the contents into it and it was successfully read but the original isn't working.

The code does not throw an exception I just end up with a `DataTable` with zero rows.

*Edit 1* One of my coworkers has pointed out that their .xlsx file is created in access.

*Edit 2* The Access created .xlsx file does open normally in Excel.
There are no blank lines at the beginning of the file.

*Edit 3* I changed the extended properties to: `Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=No""`. With this I am reading the column names but still not any of the data in the following row. Note that there is only one line in addition to the headers in the file.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could resolve this issue?

Comment: Well, not too much can be said really.  The problem must be some difference in either naming or formatting of the spread sheets from the different sources.  Start by checking the Sheet names match exactly, including casing.

Comment: @Hursey - I have checked the sheet names - the code grabs the first (and in all cases only) sheet. They can have different names but I have attempted changing the names of the sheet and manually stipulating the sheet name. Do you have ideas on the formatting that could cause the problem?

Comment: You can replace all that *schema getter* with just `dim sheet1Name = connection.GetSchema("Tables").Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()`. If you get the correct sheet name (e.g., `Sheet1$`), you have to verify whether you have empty rows at the beginning of the worksheet. In that case, you may have to specify a range along with the Sheet Name, e.g., `$"SELECT * FROM [{sheet1Name}A3:ZZ]"`. I suppose the file path is correct and it's pointing to an existing+filled `.xlsx` file. Btw, you don't need `connection.Open()` when you use a DataAdapter.

Comment: Will these Access generated files open in a normal manner in Excel?

Comment: @Mary Yes the Access generated files open normally when opened through excel.

Comment: @jimi Unfortunately I need to access the first (and always only) sheet in the excel document but the sheet is not consistently named. It may be Sheet1, NoMatch1, NoMatch2, ... ect. There are no blank rows at the top of the files.

Comment: If you're referring to the one-liner, that's simply meant to replace the methods you're using to get the name of the first WorkSheet in the WorkBook. - If you a problem with this file, post it somewhere, so it can be tested.